# Excel columns to SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, notepad++

This question is on turning the copy pasted columns from Excel into a SQL statement. My current process includes manually replacing things. After using some notepad++ functionality to control h to remove and replace all occurrences of something, and I love that notepad++ offers additional functionality. I’m just not sure how to use this functionality to get a lot closer to the end product. I feel like I can’t operate the gas and brakes normally when I have to do this, and it would be really nice to automate. Maybe I just feel that way because I know it’s probably easy, or at least it bugs me so much I think that.

Copy/paste from excel into (it looks like this is notepad++):

```
"Random
Code"   "Random
Code"   "Random
Code"   "Random
Code"   "Random
Code"   "Random
Number"
```

First, I highlight everything and replace “ (double quote) with an acute, leftquote, backtick, whatever, this symbol `

Second, I replace the blank spaces with \r\n

```
`Random`

`Code`

`Random`

`Code`

`Random`

`Code`

`Random`

`Code`

`Random`

`Code`

`Random`

`Code`
```

This gives me every word on a new line, with each surrounded by the back tick.

As you may have guessed, here is where I manually clean the rest

```
create table table_for_upload (
`Random Code`: varchar(25) null,
`Random Code`: varchar(25) null,
`Random Code`: varchar(25) null,
`Random Code`: varchar(25) null,
`Random Code`: varchar(25) null);
```

What are the unanimous next steps to get the data looking more like a SQL statement. Using notepad++ control h functionality? Or vim? Won't add the tag for vim.

Comment: Excel may be a better place to do the work.  What does it look like in Excel?

Comment: Each instance of `Random Code` represents a distinct column name?

Comment: @dougp Heh; understand. I would kindly ask if you had further thoughts on completing the process in excel. And yes, each is distinct, the representer  ```Random Code``` column name, is distinct in the sense that the spreadsheet I work with is also a two word column name that has a newline sometimes. Not too many column names are that way in the sheet. I just want to focus on those ones here.

Comment: Excel: save as .csv file.  MySQL: [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

Comment: @O.Jones sorry sorry to be clear here I just need the statement. Not actually a SQL solution to load data.

Comment: I make use of Excel's LET() formula to set up reused strings like apostrophes, commas, and spaces and nested SUBSTITUTE() functions e.g., LET(cma, ",", ap, "'", sp, " ", YOUR EXCEL FORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(CELL REFERENCE)). The LET variables lend readability to the statement and the SUBSTITUTE() function is used to clean up unwanted characters. It's necessary to escape any apostrophes from your content with double apostrophes and I do that with a nested SUBSTITUTE ().

Comment: @bugdrown I accepted the answer below. Resuming efforts to learn from your answer, it won’t be a last ditch effort. If I could accept this solution I would.

Comment: No worries. Glad you have a solution. In addition to my previous description, I put data into Excel table format. This results in column heading references rather than cell references. This increases readability as you create the formula that returns SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most parts can be done with a regular expression search and replace:

1. open the Replace dialog,
2. choose "Regular expression" as search mode
3. Find what: `[[:space:]]*"([^"]+?)(\R\R?)([^"]+)"`
4. Replace with: `'\1 \3': varchar(25) null,\2`
5. click "Replace All"
6. take care of the first line manually: insert the "create table" part
7. take care of the last line manually: replace the comma with ");"

Lets examine that `[[:space:]]*"([^"]+?)(\R\R?)([^"]+)"`:

- `[[::space::]]*` matches the optional spaces before `"Random`
- `"([^"]+?)` matches a double quote followed by everything that is not a double quote in a non greedy way and stores it in `\1`
- `(\R\R?)` takes care of the line break between `Random` and `Code` and stores it in `\2`
- `([^"]+)"` matches everything that is not a double quote followed by a double quote and stores it in `\3`
- the replace string uses the `\1,\2,\3` values from your actual line and mixes them with the constant `varchar...` string